# Proving an algebra over the Ass operad is the associative algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, operads

So i know how to prove that an algebra over the Ass operad is associative. But that doesn't mean that this algebra is the associative algebra as it might have some more structure. How would you prove that the algebra over Ass really is the Associative algebra, or is isomporhic to the associative algebra

Comment: What do you mean by "*the* associative algebra" or "*the* algebra over Ass"? Why the definite article? (It might just be a language issue.)

Comment: I would have thought that proving an algebra over Ass is an associative algebra was the easy way round. Proving that an associative algebra is an algebra over Ass is the harder way round.

Comment: Yes to using "the" is probably not the right formulation. I want to show that an associative algebra is an algebra over the Ass operad.

Comment: $Ass$ is generated by the associative binary operation, there is no more structure than that, any other operation is just a linear combination of compositions of  this operation. Because of associativity, $Ass(n)$ is a free $k$-module generated by one operation (the $n$-folf composition of the binary operation), that implies that there cannot be a "different" operation in an algebra over this operad.